# How do I make my Makefile use my CFLAGS flags when automatically compiling object files?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a Makefile for this game I'm making. It looks like this.

```
 CC = g++
 CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -w

 game: main.o item.o game.o player.o map.o room.o menu.o notebook.o enemy.o  
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o game main.o item.o game.o player.o map.o room.o menu.o notebook.o enemy.o
   mv game ../
```

I am using the
     `-std=c++11` line in the `CFLAGS` line, however, when I run `make`, I am told that I need to use C++11 since I am using the `#include <random>` line in one of my files. I hadn't noticed the compilation wasn't always using the CFLAGS line when compiling until this.

What do I need to do in order to make the automatic compilation of the object files use the `CFLAGS` also?

Comment: Are you using the implicit rules to build the `.o` files? If you're compiling c++ you need `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`. The stuff you're using is for C.

Comment: Oh geez, I didn't even realize that error. Been working in C too long. :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Specify how to generate your .o files:

```
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

As @juanchopanza mentions, you should really be using `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: I suggest adding `$(CPPFLAGS)` to be more consistent with the implicit rule.